# "Questions to" or "Questions for"?

Tags: word-choice, differences, to-for

I am writing a list of questions to be asked in an interview, and was wondering about the title of my list. Is it supposed to be called "Questions to Artists" or "Questions for Artists"? What is the right form, presuming it is me who is going to be asking the artists questions?

Comment: Either would be acceptable for your purposes, but I'd vote for "for".

Answer (score 4):

It depends.

"Questions **to** Artists" definitely refers to a collection of questions that the person writing the questions (and/or some other unspecified persons) is asking the artists for answers to. The artists are being addressed specifically.

"Questions **for** Artists" is a little less clear. It means the questions could come from other sources and not originally have been intended to be directed at the artists, but the collector of the questions deems them sufficiently important for the artists to ask (perhaps of themselves) or be asked. Or it could mean the same thing as "Questions to Artists."